# What verb can I add before information retrieval?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, verbs, phrase-request

I thought "do information retrieval" and "perform information retrieval" may be OK but seems informal. Could anyone recommend a verb which can lead information retrieval in a formal way, for instance appropriate for the verbiage in a resume?

PS: I have searched the Internet but found no such a combination. Which online tools can I use to find such usages by grammatical patterns? For example, `verb+"information retrieval"` as a query?

Comment: The issue being queried here simply wouldn't be likely to arise with most native speakers, because they wouldn't talk about ***doing*** or ***performing*** *information retrieval* in the first place. They'd normally just say they were ***retrieving information***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In some cases like writing a resume, I thought it would be necessary... Isn't it?

Comment: If I *had* to reference the act/process of "information retrieval* with a verb, the exact context would probably make a difference, but in general I'd be more likely to choose something like ***perform, implement, carry out*** rather than ***do***. But that's just a matter of personal preference (combined with *exact* context). There's no "right/wrong" issue here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Only if it is idoimatic.

Comment: It would be quite natural to say *I do information retrieval, not data analysis*. But if someone asked *What did you do at Company XYZ?* I'd probably avoid "echoing" the verb ***to do*** in the question, and reply with something like *I mainly **worked on information retrieval** during the 3 years I was there.*

Comment: From a comment, you are ***experienced at*** *information retrieval* would be common on a resume. (As a skill.) Please edit your question to provide this context.

Comment: Resumes should have action verbs when listing activities. As such, performed might be OK. It depends on the other verbs in your other bullet points. You might want to say: "*  Improved the information retrieval service" or something like that.

Comment: If the context is something like a "career resume", you might well use ***do*** for just about any "activity / sphere of competence or experience". For example, a session musician might say *I did punk rock at ABC studios, then I did classical music with the XYX orchestra.* But in "normal" contexts we'd invariably use ***played***, not ***did*** for "activities" like that.

Comment: @JasonBassford I have made an update at your request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see limited circumstances where you would want to say something like this - mostly technical, either business process or computing.

***Perform*** is perfectly formal. ***Carry out*** would also be fine. ***Do*** is less formal, you are correct.

If it's not in a technical context, then I agree with comments that this is not a natural way to say it - "retrieve data" is a more natural form.